# Why is my regex for Validating email addresses erring with "nothing to repeat"?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am learning how to use regex that would validate email addresses with the following criteria:

*user@domain.extension* to be valid if its *domain* and *extension* are **example123.com** and the value of the *user* satisfies the following constraints:

- It starts with between 1 and 6 lowercase English letters denoted by the character class [a-z]
- The lowercase letter(s) are followed by an optional underscore, i.e. zero or one occurrence of the _ character
- The optional underscore is followed by 0 to 4 optional digits denoted by the character class [0-9]

Ideally...

```
re.test(logic@example123.com) --> should return true
re.test(logic_@example123.com) --> should return true
re.test(logic_0@example123.com) --> should return true
re.test(logic2_0@example123.com) --> should return false
re.test(logic_0@gmail.com) --> should return false
```

So far I have: `const re = /^[a-z]{1,6}[_?][\d?]{0,4}+@[example123\.com]$/ig`

I'm getting an error "Nothing to repeat". I've crawled through other stackoverflow posts but still counldn't quite grasp why my pattern isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

In `\d{0,4}+`, the `+` can not be a quantifier of `{0,4}`, so it has "Nothing to repeat". It could be `\d{0,4}` or `\d+`.

Moreover, square brackets are used for character range or litteral characters. Don't use them in `[_?]`, that would be interpreted here as search for  either `_`or `?`.

As you don't want uppercase letters in your emails, you must remove the `i` modifier in your regex that would ignore case.

Try this:

```js
const re = /^[a-z]{1,6}_?\d{0,4}@example123\.com$/

console.log(re.test("logic@example123.com"));
```

Comment: Thanks @SLePort. I'm trying to understand why `\d{0,4}+` is invalid. Is it because `{0,4}` is saying I could match digits repeating 0 to 4 times, and adding `+` is redundant?   - I added the `+` sign because I wanted to connect to my `@` but now I know that's not needed. thanks again!

Comment: @jds The `+` quantifier is for "one or more". In `\d{0,4}+` you try to cumulate quantifiers("one or more zero to four"...), that won't work. You could eventually use `(\d{0,4})+` to search one or more series of 4 digits.

Comment: thanks to you @SLePort I just leveled up in regex. bug fixed. case closed :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
^[a-z]{1,6}_?\d{0,4}?@(example123\.com)$
```